# Calling Rust compiled to Emscripten produces the error Module.dynCall_ii is not a function

Tags: javascript, rust, emscripten, asm.js, webassembly

I'm following along with the [call from JavaScript](http://www.hellorust.com/emscripten/demos/04-call-into-lib/) tutorial. Instead of using node, I'm calling directly from a web browser:

**hello_world/index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head></head>
  <body>

    <script src="hello_world.js"></script>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
      var hello_world = cwrap('hello_world', 'number', []);
      var result = hello_world();
      console.log("result: ", result);
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

**hello_world/src/main.rs**

```
#![feature(link_args)]

#[link_args = "-s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS=['_hello_world']"]
extern {}

#[no_mangle]
pub fn hello_world() -> isize {
    println!("Hello World!");

    41 + 1
}

fn main() {
    // Intentionally left blank
}
```

Command:

```
cargo build --target asmjs-unknown-emscripten
```

Error message in Safari:

> TypeError: Module["dynCall_ii"] is not a function. (In
>   'Module"dynCall_ii"', 'Module["dynCall_ii"]' is undefined)

Error message in Firefox Nightly:

> TypeError: Module.dynCall_ii is not a function [Learn More](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_a_function)

If I just print the function:

```
var hello_world = cwrap('hello_world', 'number', []);
console.log("function: ", hello_world);
```

I get (on Firefox Nightly):

> function:  function asm._hello_world()

Comment: Have you had a look at the Emscripten output? That might give you a hint as to why the function won't run.

Comment: Why did you decide to ignore the **next** tutorial that [explains how to Embed Wasm in HTML](http://www.hellorust.com/emscripten/demos/06-wasm-in-html/)?

Comment: @Shepmaster I want to *call* Rust from the web browser. The tutorial you linked to only demostrates how to *run* Rust in a web browser (if that makes sense).

Comment: @Aurora0001 I will as soon as I get back home, but the function is clearly there (right?) since printing the function (without calling it) works fine, which is odd to me.

Comment: @goo, my guess is that the function contains some invalid code for some reason (or is perhaps being invoked incorrectly) leading to this error.

Comment: The posted code works perfectly in Chrome Canary (`56.0.2920.0`), Safari (`10.0.1`), and Firefox (`50.0`). You probably aren't compiling something correctly. I'm using Rust nightly (`ba872f270 2016-11-17`) and Emscripten `1.36.14`.

Comment: @Shepmaster Thank you. I'm now using Rust nightly-2016-11-17 and it works.

Comment: @Shepmaster Should I accept your answer (after you post your response as an answer) as the correct one, delete the question, or leave it?

Comment: Can you tell me what version of Rust you had before updating? I'd prefer to link to a specific git commit that fixes the problem, and that would help narrowing it down.

Comment: @Shepmaster Sure. Rust nightly-2016-11-04